# Exclude HTML tags in a database search

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have column in database (type: text), where I store some HTML code. I want to search through that column, but I want to ignore tags. For example, if I search for 'div', I want to ignore all '< div >' or '< div ' or '< / div >'.

This is part of my where clause:

```
$tag1 = '<'.$term;
$tag2 = '</'.$term.'>';
$where_uk = " and s.html like '%". $term ."%' and not ( s.html like '$tag1' and  s.html like '$tag2') ";
```

But when I echo it, I got:

```
and s.html like '%term%' and not ( s.html like '')
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Edit:
I've solve it

```
$tag1 = '&lt;'.$term.'%';
$tag2 = '&lt;/'.$term.'&gt;';
```

echo is:

```
and s.html like '%div%' and not ( s.html like '<div%' and s.html like '</div>')
```

Could you tell me is this right way to ignore tags?

Comment: You are doing it right but when you echo and check in a browser it is trying to render a HTML element. Try any CLI to output your PHP or check Firebug response tab to be sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I query a database field but ignore the HTML markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246691/how-do-i-query-a-database-field-but-ignore-the-html-markup)

Comment: I saw it, but I didnt want to do write procedure... I solve it anyway, thanks

Comment: Your solution may show the correct query on screen, but it does not necessarily match what's in the database. As @Joy pointed out, try from command line to see the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql regexp, samething like this WHERE name REGEXP ".*[^<]$term[^\>].*";